# How to predict the trajectory of two stars such that they rotate in a circle around centre of mass which itself is in uniform motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

What will be trajectory of two stars say S1 and S2 formimg a binary system and having equal mass with no external force that are rotating about their centre of mass such that they are diametrically opposite to each other.

Now as the external force is zero therefore centre of mass moves with a constant velocity (parallel to plane of cirvle) like a free particle so what will be its trajectory in laboratory frame of reference not in centre of mass frame?

I think it will be something like a trochoid 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochoid
But will be something a little more complicated so what will it be and is there some method to work out such trajectories ?

Comment: It depends on the direction of motion of the center of mass wrt to the plane of the circle. If parallel, then you do get the trochoid  I think. If perpendicular, you get a double helix. For other directions, you get something more complicated, but you should be able to get Mathematica or something to plot it fairly easily, but somebody else will have to provide instructions :)

Comment: It is parallel to the plane of circle.

Comment: What is Mathematica is it some software ? And its not a trochoid it is different almost like it .

Comment: [Mathematica](http://wolfram.com/mathematica/)

Comment: Yeah i know about that I hVe used it for plotting graphs but how to use it for trajectories

Comment: I think I got it by solving differential equations is it correct ? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x+%3D+-3sin+(5t)+%2B+4t+,+y+%3D+3+-+3+cos(5t)

Comment: Well sorry as you said it could also be a trochoid depending on angular velocity and linear velocity of centre of mass http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x+%3D+-3sin+(t)%2B3t+,+y+%3D+-3+cos(t)+%2B+3,+0<t<25

Answer (score 0):

A typical ansatz to solve this problem is to introduce a center of mass coordinate and a reduced coordinate (a coordinate for a reduced mass). Maybe this will help you: http://www.physics.usu.edu/torre/3550_Fall_2012/Lectures/08.pdf
Basically, you decompose the motion of both stars into the motion of the center of mass and the motion of both stars around the center of mass.

Comment: I know we can decompose but how can I predict the net resultant trajectory ie considering both motion of centre of mass and rotation about it in the ground frame of reference ? Ie in other words how will the motion if stars appear to an observer on ground ?

Comment: You solve the system of differential equations for the center of mass coordinate $\vec{R}$ and the relative coordinate $\vec{r}$. Then you can use your definition of these two coordinates to solve for the two stars $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$. Since you have two equations with $\vec{R}$ and $\vec{r}$ and two variables $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$, you can solve this for the trajectories of the stars.

Comment: Isn't there a more physical / intuitive way to do this only to get a rough idea about what trajectory might look like ?